# Handling DropBox with different Build Variant

Tags: android, dropbox-sdk, build-variant

I'm facing an issue with dropbox in my 2 apps.
in fact I have 2 build variants and to be able to handle different secrets for both apps I use Gradle to inject the value into the manifest but for dropbox, i always have this error

```
The installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER
```

what I did is I added in the manifest `dropboxAppKey` in the scheme attribute

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="db-${dropboxAppKey}" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and in Gradle i inject the app key corresponding to each flavor

```
 App1 {
          manifestPlaceholders = [dropboxAppKey : "123456"]
       }
 App2 {
          manifestPlaceholders = [dropboxAppKey : "654321"]
       }
```

but I got always the same error `INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a distinct app key for each variant (so, a total of 4 app keys in this case; 2 per app) in order to disambiguate each app variant.

Open a Dropbox API ticket from the account that owns the apps and we can add an extra app key/secret to each of your apps:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

That way, you can use a distinct key in each variant.

Comment: in fact i'm already using different app key for each app1Release and app2Release, each one of them have a different app key.
when installing app1 everything is fine and working perfectly but i cannot install app 2 unless i uninstall app 1